# partial fraction i can't figure it out

Tags: partial-fractions

$$X(s)=\frac{4s+1}{s(2s^2+2s+1)}$$

Please somebody show me how to factor this out step by step so I can take the inverse laplace using tables. I already have the answer:  $1+(3e^{0.5t})\sin0.5t-(e^{0.5t})\cos0.5t$

The partial fraction is difficult to handle. I've tried repeatedly and still can't get it. I need detailed steps please.

Comment: I hope nobody submits another answer, so this "damn" and the "jesus" in the text disappear from the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quadratic factor $2s^2+2s+1$ is irreducible. You should write it as $2[s^2+s+1/2]=2[(s+1/2)^2+1/4]$. From there, you should be able to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Write the expression as a sum:
$$
\frac{A}{s} + \frac{Bs + C}{2s^2 + 2s + 1} = \frac{4s+1}{s(2s^2 + 2s + 1}.
$$
Combine terms:
$$
\frac{A(2s^2 + 2s + 1) +  (Bs + C)s}{s(2s^2 + 2s + 1} = \frac{4s+1}{s(2s^2 + 2s + 1}.
$$
The two numerators must be equal, so 
$$
A(2s^2 + 2s + 1) +  (Bs + C)s = 4s+1 \\
2As^2 + 2As + A +  Bs^2 + Cs = 4s+1 \\
(2A+B)s^2 + (2A+C)s + A = 4s+1 \\
$$

from which you see that 
$$
A =1\\
2A + C = 4\\
2A + B = 0
$$
That gives $A = 1, C = 2, B = -2$. 
Thus
$$
\frac{4s+1}{s(2s^2 + 2s + 1} = 
\frac{A}{s} + \frac{Bs + C}{2s^2 + 2s + 1} \\
= \frac{1}{s} + \frac{-2s + 2}{2s^2 + 2s + 1}.
$$

Integrating the first term is easy. The second needs to be converted slightly:
$$
\frac{-2s + 2}{2s^2 + 2s + 1} 
= \frac{(-2s - 1) + 3}{2s^2 + 2s + 1} \\
= \frac{(-2s - 1)}{2s^2 + 2s + 1} +  \frac{3}{2s^2 + 2s + 1}
$$

The first term now yields to thte substitution $u = 2s^2 + 2s + 1, du = 2(2s + 1)$. The last term has to be solved with an arctan-type substitution via completion of the square.